# Variable scope puzzle, prints undefined for variable declared inside function

Tags: javascript, scope

```
var a = 2;
var b = function(){
    console.log(a);
    var a = 1;
};
b();
```

When I call b, it prints undefined.  What is the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Inside a function, `var` declares a function-scoped variable. That means it's visible to the function. The *entire* function. That means you are print out the variable before assigning a value to it.

```
var a = 123;
(function () {
    a = 456;         // Changes the function's "a"
    console.log(a);  // Outputs the function's "a": 456
    var a;           // At compile-time, declares a function variable named "a".
})();
console.log(a);      // Outputs the global "a": 123
```

Along the same line, repeating the declaration doesn't do anything. The following prints out `123`.

```
(function () {
   var a = 123;
   var a;
   console.log(a);  // 123
})();
```

Comment: but in global scope its already declared..so why its not printing 2 ?

Comment: @mahigupta, Function-scoped variables have precedence. If it didn't, `var a = 123; (function () { var a = 456; alert(a); })();` would print `123`.

Comment: @mahigupta, If you mean to ask *why aren't JS variables scoped from where they are declared to the end of the block or the next declaration of the same name?*, I have no idea. Worst JS "feature".

Answer (score 1):

The `var a` in your code is a *variable declaration* that declares a variable within the scope of its containing function. Due to *variable hoisting*, variable declarations (like `var a`) are *hoisted* to the top of their containing function. While any *declaration* is hoisted, assignments to that variable are *not* hoisted, Thus, your code is equivalent to:

```
var a = 2;
var b = function(){
    var a; // hoisted declaration; declares `a` within this function scope
    console.log(a);
    a = 1; // not-hoisted assignment
};
b();
```

Since a declared variable is `undefined` until it is given a value, this code logs `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
var a = 2;
var b = function(){
    console.log(a);
    var a = 1;
};
```

During the run time it becomes:

```
var a = 2, b;
b = function(){
    var a; // new variable declaration with no value assigned
    console.log(a); // You used it new "a" without assigning any value
    a = 1;
};
```

Inside the function the `a` is a new variable because of `var` keyword and `JS` is taking this new `a` in account which is undefined not the global `a`. Tow variables with same name,  one is outside the function (in global scope) and another is inside the function. Since there is a new variable available inside the function so it's being used in `console.log(a)` but no value assigned.

You may read [JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) and [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) on `MDN`.